# Header Values are coming as null in Apache camel Exchange

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-camel-cdi

Below are my web-service request, Route and Request-Validator,

Web-service request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <stlh:SabreHeader xmlns:stlh="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Header/v02_01">
      <stlh:Service version="1.0.0">GetHotelMediaRQ</stlh:Service>
      <stlh:Identification>
        <stlh:CustomerID>CID12345</stlh:CustomerID>
        <stlh:CustomerAppID>AppTest</stlh:CustomerAppID>
        <stlh:ConversationID>05EFPElI2A4KudU75863JIxqAhQJtAx0</stlh:ConversationID>
        <stlh:MessageID>4DTTQaHGSifFUtmSoMHAiq</stlh:MessageID>
        <stlh:TimeStamp>2014-11-07T14:45:42.725-06:00</stlh:TimeStamp>
      </stlh:Identification>
    </stlh:SabreHeader>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" wsu:Id="athId">${athId}</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetHotelMediaRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/hotel/media/v1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://services.sabre.com/hotel/media/v1 GetHotelMediaRQ.xsd">
      <HotelRefs>
        <HotelRef HotelCode="184769" CodeContext="Sabre">
          <ImageRef MaxImages="1">
            <Images>
              <Image Type="ORI"/>
            </Images>
           <AdditionalInfo>
              <Info Type="CAPTION">true</Info>
            </AdditionalInfo>
            <Languages>
              <Language Code="EN"/>
            </Languages>
          </ImageRef>
        </HotelRef>
      </HotelRefs>
    </GetHotelMediaRQ>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

RequestValidator:

```
  public void validate(GetHotelMediaRQ request, Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        TransactionContext context = BusExtensions.getTransactionContext(exchange);
        Collection<HotelRef> hotelRefList = getInstance().convert(request, Collection.class);
        Set<Property> properties = new HashSet<>();
        String customerAppId = exchange.getIn().getHeader("customerAppID", String.class);
        String customerId = exchange.getIn().getHeader("customerID", String.class);
```

But customerAppId(AppTest) and CustomerId(CI12345) is coming as null when I try to access via Exchange object.

Comment: Try using "CustomerID" or "stlh:CustomerID" instead of "customerID"

Comment: I tried both the options pat , it's not working , When i debugged the values are not present in the Header !!

Comment: then better set it in the body and try passing

Answer (score 1):

"Custom" Soap headers are not copied to camel header . you have to manually add soap header into camel exchange header .

Approach 1 )

**CamelCxfMessage -** you can extract/process custom soap header camel cxf message which is present in camel exchange header

in camel - 
SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage)exchange.getIn().getHeader("**CamelCxfMessage"**);

this will give you soap message and its soapMessage.getExchange and try to get soap headers from soap message and process it .

Approach 2)

**Camel Cxf Binding** -you can use camel cxf binding feature in endpoint definition like cxfBinding=#**bindingName** .

Create a class and extend with org.apache.camel.component.cxf.DefaultCxfBinding and bean name should be **bindingName** .

it has one method which you have to overwrite - **propagateHeadersFromCxfToCamel**(camelmessage ,cxfmessage ,exchage ).

Here get your soap header and put it in camel header with **identifier** and access header in camel exchange header in processor or routes with same **identifier**.

Answer (score 0):

Set logging for org.apache.camel to DEBUG and the header values will be logged, and you can determine if the component is dropping them or not.

Also, it looks like you might be using the cxf soap endpoint. Look into the [Description of relayHeaders option] section of the docs here:

http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html

Answer (score 0):

i had to extract header information but got null in the object at the first attempt. then after a while i could fish it out. here is how (in a processor):

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exc) throws Exception {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<SoapHeader> headers = exc.getIn().getHeader(Header.HEADER_LIST, List.class);
    for (int i=0; i < headers.size(); i++) {

        if (headers.get(i).getObject() instanceof ElementNSImpl) {
            ElementNSImpl elementNSImpl = (ElementNSImpl) headers.get(i).getObject();
            Node firstChild = elementNSImpl.getFirstChild();
            log.trace("header: name=" + elementNSImpl.getLocalName() + ", value=" + firstChild.getNodeValue());
        }
    }
```